# mvn test not working when Java 9 module is depending on automatic module

Tags: java, maven, java-module

I have a multi-module maven project with two (maven) modules `core` and `service`. `core` is too difficult to turn into a java 9 module at this stage, so we want it as an automatic module. `service` is a Java 9 module and depends on `core`.

When I run `mvn package` everything runs fine, `core` is packaged as a jar file and gets picked up as an automatic module.

However, `mvn test` throws error `module not found: core` - this is because `core` doesn't get packaged as a jar file and therefore is not picked up as an automatic module. I've created a [reproducer](https://github.com/REslim30/maven-test-automatic-module-repro) for this scenario (just imagine core is very difficult to turn into a java 9 module) - try running `mvn package` vs `mvn test`.

Is there a way to allow `mvn test` to properly run **without** turning `core` into a java 9 module?

Answer (score 0):

A valid workaround is to package `core` during the `process-classes` phase.

In `core/pom.xml`

```xml
    <build>
      <pluginManagement>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <executions>
            <!-- Runs the maven-jar-plugin goal straight after compile phase. This allows mvn test and mvn compile
            to work properly because a jar must be created in order for core to be registered as an automatic
            module. Can be removed when core is turned into a named module. -->
            <execution>
              <id>repositioned-jar</id>
              <phase>process-classes</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>jar</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
            <!-- Disables default maven-jar-plugin goal by attaching to non-existant phase.
              Remove when "reposition-jar" execution is removed -->
            <execution>
              <id>default-jar</id>
              <phase>none</phase>
              <goals>
                  <goal>jar</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      <pluginManagement>
    <build>
```

This allows a .jar to be created before the `test` phase. Tests run from IntelliJ, however, will no longer work.